# Is "completabilty" an actual word, and if not, what's a valid replacement?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for the `ability of something to be completed, or fulfilled`. My situation is specifically about sales orders.

I found `completability`, and [wiktionary.com](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/completability) says it's a word, but none of the dictionaries referenced at [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/completability) include it.

If it is indeed not a valid word, what would be a suitable alternative?

Comment: It is an easily parseable word that is formed in a regular, transparent manner and has a clear and unambiguous meaning. That makes it a valid word to me. The fact that it's not in dictionaries just means it hasn't been coined and used enough times in writing to register on the lexicographers’ radars—doesn't mean it's not a valid word, just that it's not a word people use (or need, probably) very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'd be fine using it. If you want an alternative you can use, in a subjective order of completeability: feasible, doable, possible.

Adding some links for [how words are added to dictionaries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq/words_in.htm) and [some recent additions](http://public.oed.com/whats-new/). I would say if "bestie" is added by OED, you'd have no problem using completeability.

Comment: Fascinating, though I guess it makes perfect sense.